# How to Handle a “Bus Ticket” (fine) in Italy?

Tags: italy, buses

I’m an American. I had a brand new and valid bus pass, but received a “bus ticket” (fine) in Florence, because I didn’t realize I had to stamp my own bus pass at a machine.

**My question is, because they force you to give up your passport number when cited, will they have any ability to go after me for the money, whether it is in the USA or If/when I enter another EU country?**

Comment: So your question is essentially "can I get away with not paying a fine, because I think it was imposed unfairly"?

Comment: More like, “has anyone else received this fine, not paid it and had any trouble when entering another EU country?”.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to help clarify your question, because clear, concise questions are more likely to get answered. But of course you can keep your question as it is, if you wish. Actually, I think you'll find [the answers in this question reassuring](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69070/leaving-italy-without-paying-a-fine-for-a-bus-fare-violation). Everyone there is of the opinion (and I agree) that this will have zero chance of ever affecting your future travels.

Comment: Technically, if you had not stamped your pass, you did _not_ have a valid bus pass.  Believing you had a valid pass is not the same as having a valid pass.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just pay the fine and learn your lesson for next time? If you think you're going to be travelling again, is it really worth the risk and the worrying every time you do so? I would guess the fine is not that much, probably less then Euro 50 or so? If you can afford to travel to Italy, you can probably afford to pay the fine.

I totally get that it feels like you were screwed over and that you are giving in by paying, so it's up to you have much it's worth to you to stick to your guns. Life isn't always fair.

Update: Based on your comments, I am not sure that you understand how those bus passes work. It's not just valid 90 minutes from when you purchase, it's valid 90 minutes from when you validate it (start your journey). So by not validating, you could theoretically use the pass again afterwards. This is very typical in much of Europe, and getting fined for not validating is also normal. You can't expect the bus driver to keep track of everyone who gets on the bus and when.

Comment: It’s 55 euro per person, which isn’t going to end my world, but frankly, I’d rather burn it than allow them to steal it from me. If there’s no repercussions, then of course I won’t pay. A scam is a scam, whether legal or not. “Sticking to my guns” is why this question exists. If you have actual experience in this situation, please advice, else please go enjoy yourself doing something.

Comment: Why do you think it's a scam?

Comment: Perhaps it was you trying to scam the system?  Buy the ticket but don't validate it.  If caught, use the excuse you only just boarded so clearly you didn't realize.  If not caught, then later validate the ticket and use it for a different 90 minute period.  I'm not suggesting that's what you planned, but the inspectors have no way of knowing it wasn't your plan all along!

Comment: Where was the machine you were supposed to use to validate the bus pass? At the terminal and available before you boarded, or on the bus itself?

Comment: Please don't throw around words like 'scam' when the reality is there were rules, you didn't follow them, and now don't want to face the legitimate punishment.

Comment: @BlueishVelvet if you, as a guest in someone else's house, don't like the rules - then don't enter the house. Remember also that ETIAS will be introduced in 2021. If you are registered as a person who regularly disregards local laws and regulations, you may be debarred from entering the EU - just as EU citizens are debarred from the US (ESTA) for the same (and often less) reasons.

Comment: Why do you call it scam is a mystery. @BlueishVelvet