# Old Turin bus fine never sent me the letter to pay

Tags: buses, turin

I am looking to try find out where and how I can pay a bus fine from a few years ago in Turin. They never sent me a letter in the post, but took my passport details for forgetting and not knowing to validate and stamp my bus ticket .
I am concerned that one day they will not let me back in the country .

Is there a way I can pay this? Or a website / contact to find an old penalty they never sent me the letter for?

Any help would be much appreciated

Regards

Comment: In the European Union, an entry ban for a one time failure to pay a bus fine would be considered an **unportionable** reaction. After the introduction of the [Entry/Exit System (EES)](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/smart-borders/ees_en) (expected around 2022), Border Guards may see such entries (by exit or entry) and demand payment. One reason for the slow implementation is to insure that the needed infrastructure is installed everywhere and cannot be misused.

Comment: Thank you for this information I greatly appreciate it. Do you know if I am able to somehow contact or pay online somehow ? As I mention I have no letter or details of a website where I can log in to do so.

Comment: How long ago was this? And how much was the fine?

Comment: @Traveller A few years ago. At the present rate € 300. It's probably been forgotten.

Comment: Hello Mark, thank you so much for all this information I am so appreciative you took the time and effort, very helpful. The fine was 2018 and was to be 60 euros which they were to send a letter to me in the post. I was on a bus and as a tourist didn’t know I had to validate and stamp the ticket I purchased , so I am wanting to pay as it was my mistake .

Comment: @MarkJohnson are you completely sure that the EES can be used to enforce credit and fine collection at the border? I read that it will be used to enforce **serious** crime

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ It was part of the original concept, that was originally written many years ago (thus the use of the word *may*). For serious crimes there are other databases.

Comment: Understood. The requirement could have been waived in the years

Comment: There were similar questions before: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144853/how-to-handle-a-bus-ticket-fine-in-italy?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1):

Credit and sanction collection vary internationally.

Please make sure that the *few* years ago don't exceed the 5 years credit collection limit, after which the fine is void.

At the present time a bus ticket or traffic sanction is not a valid refusal reason for the EU/Schengen area.

International traffic* sanctions can be enforced only by means of credit collection bureaus. The bus company is required to give the documentation to a credit collector that operates in your country, but it is also important that the two countries have bi-lateral agreements to enforce credit collection and guarantee legal validity to claims.

If there are no bilateral agreements, you can safely trash any collection letter as this won't be ever enforceable on your local court.

I don't have detailed info but in general in Europe if there is no law provision to **detain** you in such cases of fare evasion. Even if you visit Europe/Italy again no one will be legally allowed to say "Sir, you must follow the police now and can't leave until you have paid the fine".

This because European law**s** (namely, local laws in the context of European countries) strongly distinguish between *civil* violations and *criminal* violations, unlike for example the US system in which this could be likely considered **misdemeanor** and worth an arrest.

*Note: I wanted to improperly use the English word `traffic` to include ticket evasion into the scope. As a non-native English speaker, I don't exactly know if the scope of `traffic` violation is limited to driving motor vehicles or extends to public transport

Comment: Thank you all for the very helpful information. I suppose I just have to wait until they send me the bill in the post (as they still have not sent it) and then pay when it comes. 

Thank you again very much

Comment: Make sure that the bill gets *notified* according to your country's rules by signed mail. Without proof of delivery, the delivery never existed and you can **legally** claim you never got it (e.g. the bill won't stand small-claims court)

Answer (score -1):

Below is the (translated) text found at the Turin local transportation company.

I found no specific information about where to report if they forgot to send you the fine (may be a situation that doesn't happen that often).

> **CALL CENTERS**
> Toll-free number Information is available from the GTT toll-free number: **800-019152**, Monday to Saturday from 6.30 am to 7.30 pm (excluding holidays). The **automatic answering machine** provides 24h, 7/7 service.

As to whether the **automatic answering machine** also *parla inglese*, I cannot say.

---

> **Sanctions**:
> **Urban and suburban service (including metro)**
> For customers without a travel document or in possession of an irregular travel document, the penalty is set at € 300.00 plus the travel document (€ 1.70), with the possibility of reconciling the irregularity pursuant to paragraph 4 of art. 20 of regional law 1/2000, paying the reduced sum of € 100.00 (plus travel ticket of € 1.70) within sixty days of the dispute or notification. If payment is made within 7 days of the dispute, the penalty is reduced to € 51.00 plus the travel ticket (€ 1.70). The customer can also regularize the public transport contract by direct payment to the Customer Assistants of the sum of € 35.00 plus the travel ticket (€ 1.70).
> If the user sanctioned for not possessing a suitable and valid travel document proves, within 7 days of the dispute or notification, that he / she is in possession of a pass or a free circulation card valid at the time of the infringement, it is subject to the sanction equal to the price of the normal ticket at the ordinary rate in addition to the costs of the procedure, for a total of € 16.70. If the user does not make use of this option, that is, after the seventh day of the complaint has passed, he is required to pay a penalty of € 17.00 plus procedural costs, for a total of € 32.00.

---

**Sources**:

- [GTT - GRUPPO TORINESE TRASPORTI - Sanctions](http://www.gtt.to.it/cms/biglietti-abbonamenti/332-sanzioni)